# Should I erase pencil marks on primed trim before painting

Tags: paint, trim

Trim is primed mdf and contains a lot of pencil marks for measurements.  Should I erase the pencil marks before painting over top?  Unprimed mdf same question.

Paint is off white latex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pencil marks will not have much effect on paint adhesion, and will not cause staining, but they may show through light-coloured paints.

So yeah either do a test to see if they show through, or just erase them.

Comment: seems like they show through one coat but go away after two coats of white interior semi-gloss trim paint.